# Is there a way to send Text or Strings to Cortana similar of that to the Windows Search bar?

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

EDIT: Is there a way to "speak" to Cortana similarly to the Search box on windows computers? I don't want to create new commands but, just be able to use Cortana through typing and pre-defined strings without having to use a microphone.

Comment: You want to do something like have a string of text read out over the speaker, and have Cortana react as if it was actually spoken by the user of the computer, or am I misunderstanding your request?

Comment: That is what I want to do or if I could send her a string or something to her that would work too

Comment: It looks like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands) might be what you are looking for?

Comment: From what I read it sounds like this is for creating commands, what about commands that are already built into Cortana like "Call John Doe" or "What's the weather like today"? Or did I read that wrong?

Comment: It talks about get commands from an XML file. All I want to do is send known commands to Cortana via text instead of voice through a Unity UWP app.

Comment: I'm not sure, this is outside the scope of anything I've tried to do myself.

Answer (score 1):

> All I want to do is send known commands to Cortana via text instead of voice through a Unity UWP app.

Well, there are many uri schemes within Cortana. You could use it to launch Cortana to get result. You could use the [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) method to launch a URI.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-cortana://search/?q=web:uwp"));
```

You could also use `Run` window(<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to run the following quick command.

```
ms-cortana://search/?q=web:uwp
```

[image]